# Node js - Done is not a function after insertion in database

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im trying for the first time to do an authentification in node js. THe insertion in database is working but i've got an issue about the done function and i dont understand why. It's surely a simply answer but im still a beginner in node. Im using express and passeport for the authentification.

My code :

```
// DB
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-       local").Strategy;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection =     mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

// BD PASSEPORT
connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);

module.exports = function (passport) {
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE id = ? ", [id],
        function (err, rows) {
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
});

passport.use(
    'local-signup',
    new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        mailField: 'mail',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
        function (req, username, mail, password, done) {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE username = ? ",
                [username], function (err, rows) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    if (rows.length) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That is already taken'));
                    } else {
                        var newUserMysql = {
                            username: username,
                            mail: mail,
                            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)
                        };
                        
                        var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO client (username, mail, password) values (?, ?, ?)";

                        connection.query(insertQuery, [newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.mail, newUserMysql.password],
                            function (err, rows) {
                                newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;
 console.log(newUserMysql);
                                return done(null, newUserMysql);
                            });
                    }
                });
        })
);
```

the problem is the last done funciton :

The output

```
  {
  username: 'eazeazea',
  mail: 'eazeazeaze',
  password:    '$2a$10$iUOYeqzQqV6hJ.WvYMom8uesUxxtKpKfdb8GcoJ4Chkv ka.FIZfiO',
  id: 20
  }
   D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql  \lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
   throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
   ^

  TypeError: done is not a function
  at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Projets\group-780053    \config\passport.js:51:44)
  at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Projets\group-780053  \node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
  at Query._callback (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
  at Query.Sequence.end (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
  at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
  at Query.OkPacket (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:74:10)
  at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
   at Parser._parsePacket (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
   at Parser.write (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
   at Protocol.write (D:\Projets\group-780053\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! node-loginregister@ start: `node  ./server`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the node-loginregister@  start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with    npm. There is likely additional logging output   above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nicol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-16T10_30_48_382Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `passport.use` when is use to rename the strategie the signature, is like this

```
passport.use('new-name', new LocalStrategy(options, (req, email, password, done) => {
     // ....
}))
```

To be more specific to your example It should look like this.

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function((req, email, password, next) {
    // ...
})));
```

But in your case you passed **5** parameters, and the parameter which is named `done` in your case is the fifth parameter.
When passport will call that method function which is the `verify` as named in the code of [passport-local sources](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/4d9fbefeba48164c43d5bde4e48ff57c2c37d372/lib/strategy.js#L42)

it will be passed only 4 parameters and they won't be any fifty parameter, so it will be undefined.

Your code just means you are trying to pass parameter to `undefined` which will obviously through an error. to fix that you will make this changes

replace this line

```
function (req, username, mail, password, done) { }
```

with

```
function (req, email, password, done) { }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks to your answer, just a question. If im doing that how can i use the username that i need in my function?

Comment: Generaly when you are performing login your are only providing two information `username` or `email` and `password`. You don't provide three information `(username, email, passord)` so what you should do is in your form you specify that the user specify they email address. and the field in the form should be named as `username`. After all that what you'll have to do is to rename `email` to `username` and that's all

Comment: Alright i understand, i've got my answer ! thanks dude

Comment: the localstrategy as only two fields which are named respectively `usernameField` and `passwordField`. There isn't `mailField` as you did in your code